# Placing an image in a button and changing between images

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm fairly new to web designing, and as the question states, I want to put an image to a button, and when that image is clicked it would switch to another one.

So I figured I would break it up into task, buy first placing a button, putting an image, switching the image.

This is going to sound so silly but I can't even get the image to appear in the button.

```
<button style="display:block; background: url(../images/blackk.jpg)) no-repeat center;">
    Push me!
</button>
```

Can you please advise me on what to do ?

Comment: In stackoverflow you should post some code so we can help you out. This is not the place to just ask stuff and we'll do the job. Sorry if I sound like an old teacher but you should follow the rules around here!

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: search **how to set background image of a button** then **how to change image of button on button click**

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to get this done! First you should add a `button` tag and inside it insert an `img` tag to show off an image.

Also for changing its image by clicking on it, you might want to use jQuery library. If you are already using it, below is a code snippet to change its image.

However if you would prefer to using pure JavaScript, a simple line of code can get this done.

```
document.getElementById('foo').src = 'new srouce address';
```

---

**Demonstration:**

```js
$('#foo').click(function(){
  // another image
  $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="foo">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"/>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can set the initial image by using CSS as in*

```
<style>
.button
   {
     background: url("img_tree.png") no-repeat;
     cursor:pointer;
 }
</style>
```

*Then using on-click function on the button:*

```
<button id="imgButton" type="button" class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set background image</button>
```

*Use javascript in the function to change the image background of the button:*

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("imgButton").style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
    document.getElementById("imgButton").style.backgroundImage = "url('html5.gif')";
}
</script>
```